# Modify cmake arguments in gradle for instrumented tests in Android project with C++ library

Tags: android, c++, gradle, cmake

I have an Android project that uses native C++ library. Some library methods are getting called from the Java side via JNI. I want to write an instrumented test in Java that would test my JNI implementation (not the native library; I want to make sure that my JNI code works correctly). My plan is to use a mocked C++ class for that, which would be instantiated in the same JNI method as the real class when the test is running. I thought to achieve that by passing a parameter to cmake inside build.gradle. My problem is: in build.gradle, how can I distinguish when I'm running the test from a real app run?

More details with some code:

My JNI code:

```
#define JNI_METHOD(return_type, method_name) JNIEXPORT return_type JNICALL Java_com_myproj_Session_##method_name

extern "C" {

std::shared_ptr<my::ISession> session;

JNI_METHOD(void, init)(JNIEnv *env, jobject) {
// want I want to do here:
#ifdef TESTCONFIG
    session = std::make_shared<my::MockedSession>()
#else
    session = std::make_shared<my::Session>();
#endif
}
```

In the above both Session and MockedSession would inherit from ISession.

Then, in build.gradle I set CMake arguments:

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-Wall"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                // here I want to do the following:
                if (test) {
                    arguments "-DTESTCONFIG"
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I set 'test' flag in build.gradle?
I have tried

```
 testOptions {
      properties.put("test", "true")
}
```

and then check if testOptions.properties contain "test" key before I set Cmake parameters, but that always returned false.
I am not too good with gradle, I probably miss an obvious way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took a different approach to achieve what I wanted.

I learned that it isn't possible to pass a test = true flag from Gradle to a c++ class before the native library is built, because essentially, Gradle doesn't know if it will be built for tests or for real run. So adding a cmake argument won't work, same as trying to modify or add a Gradle task.

What I did instead:

In my JNI code:

```
#define JNI_METHOD(return_type, method_name) JNIEXPORT return_type JNICALL Java_com_myproj_Session_##method_name

extern "C" {

std::shared_ptr<my::ISession> session;
// flag for running tests
bool isTest = false;

JNI_METHOD(void, init)(JNIEnv *env, jobject) {

  if (isTest) {
      session = std::make_shared<my::MockedSession>();
  }
  else {
      session = std::make_shared<my::Session>()
  }
}

// for tests - set test run
JNI_METHOD(void, setTestRun)(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jboolean isTestRun) {
  isTest = (bool)isTestRun;
}
}
```

In my Session.java class add a method to set test flag, with package access level - so it is visible for tests but not for my library users

```
native void setTestRun(boolean isTest);
```

And then in my test, SessionTest.java, I call

```
Session session = new Session();
session.setTestRun(true);
```

This way I am able to use mocked C++ class for Java instrumented tests.